# MYSQL query of one table that is a many to many relationship to another table

Tags: mysql, database

I have a table in MySQL of products that were created in different years. attributes include id, name and year. I have another table that has a relation ship between products "DependentProduct" that has attributes id, p1id, and p2id such that product with id=p2id depends on product with id=p1id.
I am trying to find out for all products created in year 2000, how many of the products created in year 2001 depend on them. so if i have 10 products created in 2000, and 20 products created in 2001, I would like to get something like this:

```
pid    2001
1       5
2       10  
3       9
.       .
.       .
10      3
```

meaning that 5 of the products created in 2001 depend on pid 1, which is a product created in 2000. it could also be the case that some products that were created in 2001 depend on many products in year 2000.

Thanks a lot for your help

Comment: Instead of describing the table, can you just post the column lists here, and then write something explaining the format of the data you want out of it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a join

```
SELECT t2.* FROM table1 t1
INNER JOIN table2 t2 ON (t1.id = t2.tbl1_id)
WHERE t1.date = '2011-08-20'
```